# C converting an int to a bitshift operator

Tags: c, logic, bit-manipulation

I can only use these symbols:

! ~ & ^ | + << >>

Here is the table I need to achieve:

```
input | output
--------------
0     |   0
1     |   8
2     |   16
3     |   24
```

With the output I am going to left shift a 32 bit int over.

Ex.

```
int main()
{
   int myInt = 0xFFFFFFFF;
   myInt = (x << (myFunction(2)));

  //OUTPUT = 0xFFFF0000
}

int myFunction(int input)
{ 
   // Do some magic conversions here
}
```

any ideas????

Comment: Homework or interview question?  Also, not sure how the input coorisponds to the output in your ascii example.  Is the input variable or fixed at 1 or something else?

Comment: The input variable is random {0,1,2,3} and based on that number, I need to convert it to the corresponding value in the table and in return I will shift a number to the left by that amount.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you want a function with `f(0) = 0`, `f(1) = 8`, `f(3) = 24` and so on then you'll have to implement `f(x) = x * 8`. Since 8 is a perfect power of two the multiplication can be replaced by shifting. Thus:

```
int myFunction(int input)
{
    return input << 3;
}
```

That's all.

Comment: Thank you! I was confusing moving bits values and moving numbers. Thank you so much.